# IMEI for Android Tablets?

Tags: android, imei

is Android Tablets (like Xoom) have IMEI number since they dont have telephony service? is having 3G/4G vs WiFi only tablets will effect the existence of the IMEI number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only makes sense to have IMEIs on 3G tablets. For instance in IPads, only the 3G version has IMEI, as you may check in this [website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4061).

Answer (score 0):

In other words we can say that only the devices having sim cards have an IMEI number,the rest dont,as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every tablet has a unique number which is known as IMEI, its the identification of the device, it works as same it works for MOBILE.
you can check these site for more details
[www.imeitrack.org](http://www.imeitrack.org) or [www.trackimei.co.in](http://www.trackimei.co.in)  or 3gadget.com/IMEIDetails.aspx (Note: I'm affiliated with 3gadget.com)

Answer (score 0):

IMEI is the unique identifier a phone apparatus for the telephony network... and there is no point in having an IMEI code if your device is not a phone.

So devices that support only wifi connection will not have any IMEI... and DUAL SIM devices will have TWO IMEIs one for each SIM slot.