# android imei number for tablet

Tags: android

In my application i have to get unique number of device for that i am using `TelephonyManager`.
I am able to get `imei` or `device id` in android phones but Is is possible for android tablet (Xoom) to **get unique number** ? 
I am using this code to get imei number but i am not able to get in tablet, `enter code here`

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
imei = telephonyManager1.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: i assume same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876181/imei-for-android-tablets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think IMEIs on 3G tablets only.  Try to use,

**ANDROID_ID**

More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped.

ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier. There are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

Look at [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Comment: I am not sure thats why i am asking that All the tablets have their Imei Number ?? because it related with the TelephonyManager.